# canvg is returning white screen with base64 string with angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11, canvg

```
I am trying to get a snapshot of svg present on a webpage in IE11. But, every time I am getting only white screen.

I have done till now:

        let targetElem = <any>document.getElementById('body');
        let nodesToRecover = [];
        let nodesToRemove = [];

        let svgElem = targetElem.querySelector('svg')

        let parentNode = svgElem.parentNode;
            // let svg = parentNode.innerHTML;
            let svg = "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" id=\"svg-annotations\" style=\"opacity: 1;\" _ngcontent-c7=\"\">\n\t\t\t<defs><marker id=\"arrow-start\" refY=\"4.5\" markerWidth=\"9.9\" markerHeight=\"9\" orient=\"auto\"><path fill=\"black\" d=\"M 9.9 0 L 9.9 9 L 0 4.5 Z\" /></marker><marker id=\"arrow-end\" refX=\"9.9\" refY=\"4.5\" markerWidth=\"9.9\" markerHeight=\"9\" orient=\"auto\"><path fill=\"black\" d=\"M 0 0 L 0 9 L 9.9 4.5 Z\" /></marker></defs><g class=\"annotation-group\" id=\"measurement-36122\" style=\"opacity: 1;\"><g class=\"annotations\"><g class=\"annotation callout elbow editable \" transform=\"translate(758.541 408.978)\"><g class=\"annotation-connector\"><path class=\"connector\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\" d=\"M 0 0 L 137 137 L 162 137\" /></g><g class=\"annotation-note\" transform=\"translate(162 137)\"><g class=\"annotation-note-content\" transform=\"translate(0 3)\"><rect class=\"annotation-note-bg\" fill=\"white\" fill-opacity=\"0\" x=\"0\" width=\"104.79\" height=\"41.36\" /><text class=\"annotation-note-label\" fill=\"black\" y=\"41.36\" dx=\"0\"><tspan x=\"0\" dy=\"0.8em\" /></text><text class=\"annotation-note-title\" font-weight=\"bold\" fill=\"black\"><tspan x=\"0\" dy=\"0.8em\">Face</tspan><tspan x=\"0\" dy=\"1.2em\">:5453831.5mm²</tspan></text></g><path class=\"note-line\" stroke=\"black\" d=\"M 0 0 L 104.79 0\" /><circle class=\"handle \" cursor=\"move\" fill=\"grey\" fill-opacity=\"0.1\" stroke=\"grey\" stroke-dasharray=\"5\" cx=\"0\" cy=\"0\" r=\"10\" /></g></g></g></g><g class=\"annotation-group\" id=\"measurement-59622\" style=\"opacity: 1;\"><g class=\"annotations\"><g class=\"annotation callout elbow editable \" transform=\"translate(889.656 387.507)\"><g class=\"annotation-connector\"><path class=\"connector\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\" d=\"M 0 0 L 137 137 L 162 137\" /></g><g class=\"annotation-note\" transform=\"translate(162 137)\"><g class=\"annotation-note-content\" transform=\"translate(0 3)\"><rect class=\"annotation-note-bg\" fill=\"white\" fill-opacity=\"0\" x=\"0\" width=\"104.79\" height=\"41.36\" /><text class=\"annotation-note-label\" fill=\"black\" y=\"41.36\" dx=\"0\"><tspan x=\"0\" dy=\"0.8em\" /></text><text class=\"annotation-note-title\" font-weight=\"bold\" fill=\"black\"><tspan x=\"0\" dy=\"0.8em\">Face</tspan><tspan x=\"0\" dy=\"1.2em\">:5453831.5mm²</tspan></text></g><path class=\"note-line\" stroke=\"black\" d=\"M 0 0 L 104.79 0\" /><circle class=\"handle \" cursor=\"move\" fill=\"grey\" fill-opacity=\"0.1\" stroke=\"grey\" stroke-dasharray=\"5\" cx=\"0\" cy=\"0\" r=\"10\" /></g></g></g></g></svg>";

            this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            this.canvas.setAttribute('id', '_canvas');

            canvg(this.canvas, svg, {renderCallback: function(){
                console.log(this);
            }});

            nodesToRecover.push({
                parent: parentNode,
                child: svgElem
            });
            parentNode.removeChild(svgElem);

            nodesToRemove.push({
                parent: parentNode,
                child: this.canvas
            });

            parentNode.appendChild(this.canvas);
            let data = this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.5);
            console.log(data);
```

after appending canvas to parentNode, I can see my svg on the webpage with canvas tag, but converting it to base64 is giving me only white screen. can anyone please help me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the SVG element's size (width and height). Perhaps the issue is related these property.

Since, you are using the [translate() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) on the SVG graphics, it will reposition an element in the horizontal and/or vertical directions. If the offset is larger than the SVG's size. The SVG will be displayed white screen.